# What are good sources to learn CSS positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm a newbie at HTML and DIV positioning, and I'm wondering if there is a good place for learning to advance level about DIV positioning. I am actually interested about doing layouts in HTML for different platforms (e.g. Internet Explorer, Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari, iPad).

Currently my work is looking like a bit of cooking: trying and experimenting. Somehow, this doesn't look as a good way of doing it.

Comment: "Currently my work is looking like a bit of cooking: trying and experimenting. Somehow, this doesn't look as a good way of doing it." That's the **best** way to do it.

Comment: why so many down votes for this question ?

Comment: Why down votes really? It's common for a developer to focus on (and only on) css positioning, as tinkering with all other things in css costs lots and lots of time. http://learnlayout.com/ may help you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a great place to learn about layouts and HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/.

Comment: You might also want to check out [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/), as a counterpoint.

Comment: why am I getting down votes? I never said w3school's certificate is valid nor did I EVER say that its perfect, I just said its a great place to start and ofcourse you should always check what people say on the net.

Comment: You could've at least linked to their bits on CSS positioning.

Comment: wow you get down votes easily on this site!! LOL

Comment: maybe people don't like w3schools, nothing personal (thanks for the effort)

Answer (score 1):

A very reliable website for web development (JavaScript, CSS, HTML and much more) is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/). To be more specific for your question, see [the article about position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position).

Answer (score -1):

The best resource is W3schools: [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and [CSS Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).